# Modifying Function Arguments in Python to Access Private Fields Within a Class

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to create a Class with a list of fields. See code below.

```
class Character:
    # Private Fields:
    __age = 18
    __weight = 200
    __height = 72
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name
        
    @property
    def get_age(self):
        return self.__age
    @property
    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name
    @property
    def get_weight(self):
        return self.__weight
    @property
    def get_height(self):
        return self.__height
    
person = Character("someone")

print("name =", person.get_name,",", "age =", person.get_age)
```

Is there a way to avoid writing the @property for every private field you want to access? For instance is there a way to pass an attribute into a more general getter function like:

```
def get_attr(self,attr):
    #set attr to __attr
    #return self.attr
```

I tried using the join function, but it didn't work

Thanks for any help

Comment: Use a dataclass?

Comment: Have you checked the `namedtuple()` class generator?

Comment: Can you... just access the fields directly? Getters are kind of an anti-pattern in Python, and properties are meant to create methods that look like fields. Just make the fields public.

Comment: This looks like you're trying to write Java in Python. Trying to initialize instance attributes at class level, writing getters, writing "get" in the names of those getters...

Comment: **Python doesn't have private fields**. This is *crucial to understand*. Note, all your `property`s are **utterly pointless**. Just remove them, and use regular attributes `self.name` etc, initialized in `__init__`

Comment: "Is there a way to avoid writing the @property for every private field you want to access?" yes. simply remove the double-underscores (again, **not private**, Python doesn't have access modifiers, and everything is totally public, if you want to show that something is supposed to be private, use a *single underscore*, but if you want to access them outside **then they aren't supposed to be private**)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question as asked, the simple solution is to compensate for the name mangling that is done with private members.  e.g. to get the `__age` attribute you'd use: `person._Character__age`

But, this would be a terrible idea and I wouldn't recommend it.  If you need them to be easily accessible, just remove the underscores.  If they really need to be private, they shouldn't be easily accessible from outside the class anyway, so putting in a way to make them accessible defeats the purpose.